# How can I pass a pointer to itself to C++ so it can perform a callback?

Tags: rust, ffi

I've defined a way to pass my Rust object to C++ so it can call this Rust object back:

```rust
extern "C" {
    pub fn zlmedia_set_parent(zl_media: *mut ZLInstance, parent: Box<ZLMedia>);
}

pub fn new_boxed(url: &str) -> Box<ZLMedia> {
    let c_url = CString::new(url).expect("CString::new failed");
    let p = Box::new(ZLMedia {
        zl_media: unsafe { zlmedia_new(c_url.into_raw()) },
        url: url.to_string(),
    });
    unsafe {
        zlmedia_set_parent(p.as_ref().zl_media, p);
    }
    p
}
```

The problem is that I can't pass the `Box` to C++ because I move it here:

```rust
unsafe {
    zlmedia_set_parent(p.as_ref().zl_media, p);
}
```

How can I pass a `Box` to itself to C++ and still return it in the `new`? I don't really need to move it, because it goes to a C++ function.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `ZLMedia` to be *owned* by the Rust code then you can pass a pointer to it rather then the box itself.

```
use std::borrow::Borrow as _;

extern "C" {
     pub fn zlmedia_set_parent(zl_media: *mut ZLInstance, parent: *const ZLMedia);
}

pub fn new_boxed(url: &str) -> Box<ZLMedia> {
    let c_url = CString::new(url).expect("CString::new failed");
    let p = Box::new(ZLMedia {
        zl_media: unsafe { zlmedia_new(c_url.into_raw()) },
        url: url.to_string(),
    });
    unsafe {
        zlmedia_set_parent(p.as_ref().zl_media, p.borrow() as *const ZLMedia);
    }
    p
}
```

If the C++ code dereferences the pointer after the box is dropped, it will trigger Undefined Behaviour. If the C++ code tries to free the pointer then it's also UB. It's up to you to make sure that these things don't happen.

Comment: The reason I was avoiding passing a raw pointer is that then, `ZLMedia` must be C-friendly. But I can't rely on this, it's a complex struct. If I do like this, Rust will complain about ZLMedia not being FFI-safe

Comment: I opened a little bounty, would be nice if you could help me. Thank you very muh